# MVC3 error when passing a model from controller to view while using a viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm sorry, for I'm sure there's a way to do this with a viewModel, however I'm very inexperienced with this and don't even know if I'm doing it correctly.

What I'm trying to do is pass multiple blogs and the profile info of the user who posted each blog to a view.

I'm getting the following error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'ACapture.Models.ViewModels.BlogViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ACapture.Models.ViewModels.BlogViewModel]'.

I'm trying to pass the following query results to the view.

```
        var results = (from r in db.Blog.AsEnumerable()
                       join a in db.Profile on r.AccountID equals a.AccountID
                       select new { r, a });

        return View(new BlogViewModel(results.ToList()));
    }
```

This is my viewModel

```
public class BlogViewModel
{
    private object p;

    public BlogViewModel(object p)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

And my view

```
@model IEnumerable<ACapture.Models.ViewModels.BlogViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="Forum">
    <p>The Forum</p>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="ForumChild">


                    <img src="@item.image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />
                    <br />
                        <table>
                            @foreach (var comment in item.comment)
                            {

                                <tr><td></td><td>@comment.Commentation</td></tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                </div>                
            }
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to change your view model a little to:

```
public class BlogViewModel
{
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile{ get; set; }
}
```

and then return it as follow:

```
    var results = (from r in db.Blog.AsEnumerable()
                   join a in db.Profile on r.AccountID equals a.AccountID
                   select new new BlogViewModel { Blog = r, Profile = a });

    return View(results.ToList());
```

Then in your `foreach` loop inside of view, you will get an objects that will contain both - profile and blog info, so you can use it like f.e. `@item.Profile.Username`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the ViewModel in this case, but it seems like you are expecting for the page to represent a single blog with a collection of comments.  In this case you should replace

```
IEnumerable<ACapture.Models.ViewModels.BlogViewModel>
```

With

```
ACapture.Models.ViewModels.BlogViewModel
```

Then `Model` represents a single BlogViewModel, that you can iterate over the comments by using `Model.comments` and access the image using `Model.image.img_path`.

If this not the case, and you intend to have multiple BlogViewModels per page, then you will have to actually construct a collection of BlogViewModels and pass that to the view instead.